# Softlayer SLCLI server list by pattern

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to query my list of servers, but only return servers that match a pattern; reason for this is I want to contact a specific set of servers, for example: server_apisX, and server_uiX.

I tried slcli vs list -H myhostprefix but it only matches exact matches.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementing the previous answer …

Please, try the following examples:

Hostname to test: “**myhostname-vsi-test**”

- Contains part of the hostname:

  slcli vs list –H “*=vsi”
- Begins with:

  slcli vs lsit –H “^= myhost”
- Ends with:

  slcli vs lsit –H “$= test”

**References:**

https://docs.omniref.com/ruby/gems/softlayer_api/2.1.1/symbols/SoftLayer::ObjectFilter#line=2

Answer (score 1):

slcli supports the use of filters. So you can do:

```
slcli vs list -H hostnameprefix\*
```

Just make sure to either quote or escape the special characters.

If you are curious, [utils.py provides documentation](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/blob/master/SoftLayer/utils.py#L72) about what filters can be used.